# Return QuerySet based on User group/permissions

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-permissions

I'm trying to figure out what's the "best practice" to limit `QuerySet`s based on `User`s permissions.

For example, there is a table of invoices on the dashboard. `User` that has `Group` called `Admin` can see all invoices but `User` that has group `Broker` can see only their own invoices. That means only invoices that have `user = ...`.

My idea is to create two permissions `can_see_all_invoices` and `can_see_own_invoices`.

Now when I call the `QuerySet` using `Django Rest Framework`, I'll check for the permissions and return the filtered `QuerySet`.

Or should I filter the `QuerySet` on the frontend and if `Broker` asks for all invoices I would raise PermissionError?

Which of these approaches are being used or is there a different approach?

Answer (score 0):

IMO, this would be a clean method

```
class MyInvoiceAPI:
    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Invoice.objects.all()
        if self.request.user.has_perm('can_see_all_invoices'):
            return qs
        return qs.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

### Notes

- You don't need two permissions, only one which is `can_see_all_invoices`
- I wouldn't raise any permission denied errors in this case, since it a List API, and evaluation of object is an expensive process